# Software for vocal removal?

Tags: software, vocals, isolation, removal

Is there any software which can take vocal out from tracks for recording purpose?  I am aware with Audacity but it's not 100%

First suggest me free one and than chargeable

Comment: So.. do you want to remove the vocals or remove the music?

Comment: I want to remove vocals only not music sir

Answer (score 2):

Evan if there is, it would be most likely based on stereo cancellation and eq-ing so it might be a better idea do them the proper way instead of relying on software